# Powershell multiple output variables

Tags: powershell, function, variables

I'm new at PowerShell and I'm still struggling with the basics so sorry if it seems obvious...

I've been exploring this site and the site of Microsoft but I could not figure out how to achieve the following example.

I've made a test function as below. I'd like to input variable i and output j and k.

The value of the function true/false will give its status in case it would encounter an error.

Of course, I've simplified what I want to achieve at it's extreme but it illustrates my issue.

```
function ftest {
 try {
  Param ($i,$j,$k)
  $j = $i+1
  $k = $i-1
  return $true
 }
 catch { return $false }
}

$i0 = 3
$j0 = 0
$k0 = 0

$t0 = ftest -i $i0 -j $j0 -k $k0
```

When I execute this code, step by step, everything tuns well but after the function has been processed, the variables $j0 and $k0 remain at 0 instead of respectively the expected 4 and 2.

Could anyone tell me where I'm going wrong, and how to achieve this "simple" result, please?

Comment: Move `Param()` before `try`. Then use `return j,k` to return an array. It would be more psish to return a `PSCustomObject`, but not an absolute requirement.

Comment: you have mixed up the function and the procedure

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking to do:

```bash
function ftest {
    param ($i, [ref] $j, [ref] $k)

    try {
        $j.Value = $i + 1
        $k.Value = $i - 1
        return $true
    }
    catch {
        return $false
    }
}

$i0 = 3
$j0 = 0
$k0 = 0

$t0 = ftest -i $i0 -j ([ref] $j0) -k ([ref] $k0)
$t0 # True
$j0 # 4
$k0 # 2
```

Updating the value of a variable outside the function's scope requires said variable to be a [reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/lang-spec/chapter-04?view=powershell-7.3#43-reference-types). Other alternative would be to use the [`script:` scope modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-7.2#scope-modifiers) but then `$j` and `$k` should not be passed as arguments to the function:

```bash
function ftest {
    param ($i)

    try {
        $script:j0 = $i + 1
        $script:k0 = $i - 1
        return $true
    }
    catch {
        return $false
    }
}

$i0 = 3
$j0 = 0
$k0 = 0

$t0 = ftest -i $i0
$t0 # True
$j0 # 4
$k0 # 2
```

---

What you should do instead:

```bash
function ftest {
    param ($i)

    try {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            i = $i
            j = $i + 1
            k = $i - 1
        }
    }
    catch {
        return $false
    }
}

$i0 = 3
$t0 = ftest -i $i0

# $t0:
#
# i j k
# - - -
# 3 4 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, you should use `[ref]` to pass the value by reference

```
function ftest([ref]$i, [ref]$j, [ref]$k){
  $j.Value = $i.Value + 1
  $k.Value = $i.Value - 1
}

$i = 3
$j = [ref]0
$k = [ref]0

ftest -i ([ref]$i) -j $j -k $k

Write-Host $i
Write-Host $j.Value
Write-Host $k.Value
```

Output

```
3
4
2
```

Answer (score 0):

it will be better if you use a clean function

```
function ftest{
    Param([scriptblock]$FunctionToCall,$one,$two)
    $($FunctionToCall.Invoke($one,$two))
}


$scriptBlock1 = {  
    param($one,$two)
    $one + $two
}

$scriptBlock2 = {  
    param($one,$two)
    $one - $two
}

$i0 = 1
$j0 = 1
$k0 = 1
$j0 = ftest -FunctionToCall $scriptBlock1 -one $i0 -two $j0
$k0 = ftest -FunctionToCall $scriptBlock2 -one $i0 -two $k0
$j0
$k0
```

return

```
2
0
```

You calculate each variable separately. If you need to calculate multiple variables in one function, return the result as an array.